# How automatically to identify series when creating graph

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula, timeserieschart, pivot-chart

Right now I have three columns of data that I would need on a graph. It's about the score of different countries on non-related evaluations. So there's a column for the year of the evaluation, the name of the country and the score it got.

Since there are hundreds of them, it would take a lot of time to add data series individually, so I was wondering if isn't there a way to just select the columns and Excel could identify each series automatically.

Illustrating:

Supposing I had this table:
[image: 1]

And wanted to create a graph like this:
[image: 2]

Is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot a PivotChart Line type: `Years` for ROWS, `Country` for COLUMNS and `Sum of Score` for VALUES.

[image: SO34166539 example]